# Key error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all the words and its tag and count into a dictionary. However, I keep getting a KeyError and I don't understand why.

```
sent = [[('Merger', 'NOUN'), ('proposed', 'VERB')], [('Wards', 'NOUN'), ('protected', 'VERB')]]

dicts = {}

for x in sent:
    for y in x:
        if y[0] in dicts.keys():
            dicts[y[0]][y[1]] = 1
        else:
            dicts[y[0]][y[1]] += 1
```

Error:

```
   KeyError               Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-19-17c6695bd911> in <module>()
   17             dicts[y[0]][y[1]] = 1
   18         else:
---> 19             dicts[y[0]][y[1]] += 1

   KeyError: 'Merger'
```

Comment: You got two rapid answers from high-rep people but I'm struggling to understand the usefulness of `dicts[y[0]][y[1]] += 1`. What output are you expecting?

Comment: @roganjosh hi i am trying to created a nested dictionary. so it would be {Merger:{Noun:1}}

Comment: I think it got addressed with TerryA's edited answer actually. It just didn't look right, I wondered whether something circuitous was going on.

Comment: You are trying to reference dicts nested 2 deep without first creating the inner dicts. Python doesn't know that those elements in the outer dict are dictionaries.

Comment: @PaulRooney Hi how do I go about doing this

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. You could clarify your question by providing the expected output. The part I'm struggling with is why the count? If you could include something in your input data that will causes a count of 2 for some element it would also make your intent clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider looking at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

A `defaultdict` will automatically fill in a default value, a `Counter` is a `dict` specifically for counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

sent = [[('Merger', 'NOUN'), ('proposed', 'VERB')], [('Wards', 'NOUN'), ('protected', 'VERB')]]

dicts = defaultdict(Counter)  # A default dictionary of Counters
for x in sent:
    for y in x:
        dicts[y[0]][y[1]] += 1

print(dicts)
# defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'Merger': Counter({'NOUN': 1}), 'proposed': Counter({'VERB': 1}), 'Wards': Counter({'NOUN': 1}), 'protected': Counter({'VERB': 1})})
```

If you want to skip the `Counter`, you can just use a helper function that returns a `defaultdict(int)` and takes no arguments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def int_dict():
    return defaultdict(int)

dicts = defaultdict(int_dict)
for x in sent:
    for y in x:
        dicts[y[0]][y[1]] += 1

print(dicts)
# defaultdict(<function a at 0x112c48048>, {'Merger': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'NOUN': 1}), 'proposed': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'VERB': 1}), 'Wards': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'NOUN': 1}), 'protected': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'VERB': 1})})
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was about to post, so I wont duplicate. You could avoid the ugly index access on the tuple by unpacking it in the `for in`. e.g. `for name, typ in x:`

Answer (score 1):

You've got your conditionals the wrong way round. You want to check if the key exists in the dictionary first -- if not, then you create the key. Then, you've nested too far. You only need `dicts[y[0]]`

There's an easy fix: add `not` before `in dicts.keys()`, but then get rid of `[y[1]]`.

In full:

```
for x in sent:
    for y in x:
        if y[0] not in dicts.keys():
            dicts[y[0]] = 1
        else:
            dicts[y[0]] += 1
```